# I can't guess what the file format is

Tags: format, edi

App exports data in strange way, it says it is .edi but it doesn't look like .edi...
I want to make an xml from it or something that I could use in my android app.
In my app I want to make select like "select from [Document] from Poz where Symbol=getSymbol();"

Here is an example of it:

```
[Dokument]
Rejestr=FakturyZak
[ZawartoscDokumentu]
[Poz1]
Nazwa=postionon1                    
Symbol=123
CenaNetto=0.96000
[Poz2]
Nazwa=position2
Symbol=12345
CenaNetto=0.96000
[Poz3]
Nazwa=position3
Symbol=1281
CenaNetto=14.11000
```

It should works like I write down 12345 and it will give me all CenaNetto of the position2 fields from all [Dokument] statements

The problem is that I've got plenty of statements like [Dokument], there is no ID and so on that I can iterate over it, also I've got other statements like [Info], [Pakiety]..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is structured like a lot of configuration files.
Should be fairly easy to use (lots  of libraries).
It is not one of the commonly used edi standards (edifact, x12 etc)
But a lot of ERP software uses an internal format (inhouse format) for import/export. Translation from/to eg edifact is done by edi translator.
Hope this helps.

Comment: maybe you know lib to convert this structure to xml or something else? Now i'm trying to use edi transtator.

Comment: no, not directly. Never seen this format use for edi since 1994 ;-)) From what software does this come?

Comment: Definitely not EDI, but a flat file.  The problem is you'd need to know all the record types.  You might be able to define it as an "=" delimited file.  I suggest checking with the software vendor to find all possible fields and them model that layout in your translator.  This could get ugly all day, especially if you need detail / repeating segments.

Comment: @Andrew that is a clue i needed. Thanks a lot ! Wish me luck ;)